# Lack of precision in Andres drawn circle

Tags: java, precision, trigonometry

I wrote a little program which draws a circular chromatic gradation using Andres' algorithm.
Here is the result of an execution :

[image]

If the final-user gives the program a shift, in radians, it will use the latter to begin the drawing of the circle at this angle. **Thus, the gradation will begin at this angle (and that's what I want).**

For example, you can see that the gradation begins at the bottom of the circle and not at its left in the following image.

[image]

**But as you can see, two problems appear :**

1. First, there are some gaps in the circle ;
2. Then, the circumference of the circle is quite imprecise.

**I think it's a problem of precision.** So I asked myself if there were some bad casts but it's not the case.
Well, I don't know what is the reason why my circle is so imprecise. Could you help me please ?

**Here is the class that draws each pixel of the circle. It takes on board the specified shift, in radians.**

```
/**
 * Constructs a Pixel taking account of a shift and near the position (x0 ; y0)
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @param color
 * @param angle
 * @param x0
 * @param y0
 */
Pixel(double x, double y, Color color, double angle, double x0, double y0) {
    this.x = (int) (x0 + (x-x0) * Math.cos(angle) - (y-y0) * Math.sin(angle));
    this.y = (int) (y0 + (y-y0) * Math.cos(angle) + (x-x0) * Math.sin(angle));
    this.color = color;
}
```

**Now, the code that draws the circle, using Andres' algorithm and the `Pixel` class.**

```
case "Andres' algorithm":
    w = 2 * Math.PI;

    for(double current_thickness = 0; current_thickness < this.thickness; current_thickness++) {
        x = 0;
        y = (int) (radius + current_thickness);
        double d = radius + current_thickness - 1;

        while (y >= x) {
            double octant_1_x = x0 + x, octant_1_y = y0 + y;
            double octant_2_x = x0 + y, octant_2_y = y0 + x;
            double octant_3_x = x0 - x, octant_3_y = y0 + y;
            double octant_4_x = x0 - y, octant_4_y = y0 + x;
            double octant_5_x = x0 + x, octant_5_y = y0 - y;
            double octant_6_x = x0 + y, octant_6_y = y0 - x;
            double octant_7_x = x0 - x, octant_7_y =  y0 - y;
            double octant_8_x = x0 - y, octant_8_y = y0 - x;

            max_counter++;

            double[] rgb_gradation_octant_1 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_1_y - y0, octant_1_x - x0) + Math.PI, w);
            updates.add(new Pixel(octant_1_x, octant_1_y,
                    Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_1[0], rgb_gradation_octant_1[1], rgb_gradation_octant_1[2]),
                    circle_gradation_beginning, x0, y0)); // octant n°1

            double[] rgb_gradation_octant_2 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_2_y - y0, octant_2_x - x0) + Math.PI, w);
            updates.add(new Pixel(octant_2_x, octant_2_y,
                    Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_2[0], rgb_gradation_octant_2[1], rgb_gradation_octant_2[2]),
                    circle_gradation_beginning, x0, y0));

            double[] rgb_gradation_octant_3 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_3_y - y0, octant_3_x - x0) + Math.PI, w);
            updates.add(new Pixel(octant_3_x, octant_3_y,
                    Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_3[0], rgb_gradation_octant_3[1], rgb_gradation_octant_3[2]),
                    circle_gradation_beginning, x0, y0));

            double[] rgb_gradation_octant_4 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_4_y - y0, octant_4_x - x0) + Math.PI, w);
            updates.add(new Pixel(octant_4_x, octant_4_y,
                    Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_4[0], rgb_gradation_octant_4[1], rgb_gradation_octant_4[2]),
                    circle_gradation_beginning, x0, y0)); // octant n°4

            double[] rgb_gradation_octant_5 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_5_y-y0, octant_5_x-x0) + Math.PI, w);
            updates.add(new Pixel(octant_5_x, octant_5_y,
                    Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_5[0], rgb_gradation_octant_5[1], rgb_gradation_octant_5[2]),
                    circle_gradation_beginning, x0, y0)); // octant n°5

            double[] rgb_gradation_octant_6 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_6_y-y0, octant_6_x-x0) + Math.PI, w);
            updates.add(new Pixel(octant_6_x, octant_6_y,
                    Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_6[0], rgb_gradation_octant_6[1], rgb_gradation_octant_6[2]),
                    circle_gradation_beginning, x0, y0));

            double[] rgb_gradation_octant_7 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_7_y-y0, octant_7_x-x0) + Math.PI, w);
            updates.add(new Pixel(octant_7_x, octant_7_y,
                    Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_7[0], rgb_gradation_octant_7[1], rgb_gradation_octant_7[2]),
                    circle_gradation_beginning, x0, y0));

            double[] rgb_gradation_octant_8 = PhotoRetouchingFormulas.chromatic_gradation(Math.atan2(octant_8_y-y0, octant_8_x-x0) + Math.PI, w);
            updates.add(new Pixel(octant_8_x, octant_8_y,
                    Color.color(rgb_gradation_octant_8[0], rgb_gradation_octant_8[1], rgb_gradation_octant_8[2]),
                    circle_gradation_beginning, x0, y0)); // octant n°8

            if (d >= 2 * x) {
                d -= 2 * x + 1;
                x++;
            } else if (d < 2 * (radius + thickness - y)) {
                d += 2 * y - 1;
                y--;
            } else {
                d += 2 * (y - x - 1);
                y--;
                x++;
            }

        }
    }

    gui.getImageAnimation().setMax(max_counter*8);
    break;
```

Comment: thank you for providing the link to Andres(??) `Bresenham` (!!) Circle algorithm... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Comment: Hello, it's not the Bresenham's algorithm. Both are quite similar. But I really use Andres' one : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithme_de_trac%C3%A9_de_cercle_d%27Andres (it seems to be only available in French)

Comment: oh um - seems to be identical on first glance, sorry =) have you considered to use antialiasing to improve drawing quality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm)

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else, and it would be a cheat to use anti-aliasing =/

Comment: je ne parl le francoise ^^ i'll have alook into the french page!

Comment: I don't think the problem is due to Andres (indeed, my circle is well drawn when the shift is 0°). The problem comes when the sifht is > 0° (even at 360°, there is some gaps). So I believe the `Pixel` constructor contains the problem.

Comment: yes, `Pixel`is the problem - the algorithm provides a full circle, so you don't have to do any further math on it. try to draw them plain!

Comment: Uhm, I'm not sure to understand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to 'rotate' the pixel, you just have to draw them

```
Pixel(double x, double y, Color color, double angle, double x0, double y0) {
    this.x = (int) (x + x0);
    this.y = (int) (y + y0);
    this.color = getColorForAngle(angle);
}
```

Bresenham / Andres provide all pixels of the circle, no need to translate/rotate them

Comment: In fact I want to rotate the circle thanks to the angle, that's why my `Pixel`'s constructor contains the function-calls `Math.cos(angle)`, etc. So I can't use the constructor you wrote =/

Comment: have you tried to use it so you see differences in the rendering?

Comment: But why should I use it ? There isn't any angle to take into account =/ I already draw my circle without taking account this angle, it worked ; but now I would want to rotate it ^^

Comment: you should not rotate the calculated circle, the point of calculating the circle by bresenham/Andres is the fact that it matches perfect on your rastered screen.  instead try to use the pixel coordinates and alter the color! (i have adjusted my answer)

Comment: Ah okay so according to you, I really can't modify the circle and I have to shift only the gradation ?

Comment: yes, the bresenham/Andres provide a perfrect circle for a rastered view (monitor). if you start to rotate these pixel you get rounding errors (resulting in missing pixels and inaccurate diameter).

Comment: just alter the color for each 'rotation degree'

Comment: Ah okay, well I'm quite disapointed because I must to modify all my code, but thank you ! :)

Comment: i'm really sorry to hear that - i used the algorith from besenheim for both lines and cicles and had also some trouble with it (e.g. getting a disque from a circle made me worries)